# Why is my .drop removing all values in my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I keep trying to use this line of code to remove the rows of data with NaN in a certain column but it keeps removing all rows:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.test_variable == 'NaN')].index)
```

Comment: you can try using `dropna`

Comment: may be try this `df.dropna(subset='test_variable ])`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you're *really* trying to ask (how to drop rows containing NaNs), use the [`DataFrame.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4),
    columns = ['A','B','C','D'])

df.loc[0, 'A'] = None
df.loc[1, 'B'] = None
df.loc[1, 'C'] = None

print(df)
print('------')
print(df.dropna())
```

prints:

```
$ py na.py
     A    B     C   D
0  NaN  1.0   2.0   3
1  4.0  NaN   NaN   7
2  8.0  9.0  10.0  11
------
     A    B     C   D
2  8.0  9.0  10.0  11
```

To answer the question you asked, though, this boolean check is problematic:

```
df.test_variable == 'NaN'
```

This will literally use the string `"NaN"` when checking for rows that match, instead of checking for actual NaNs. In fact, NaN is an equivalent way of saying None in Pandas, so you can use `None` instead of `"NaN"`. However, simply replacing your boolean check with `df.test_variable is None`  will still not work, because that boolean check is literally asking if `df.test_variable` (which will return a Pandas Series object) is `None` (which it is not), instead of asking which of the elements of `df.test_variable` is equal to `None`. To do the element-wise check, use the [`isna()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) of the Pandas Series object:

Start by getting the indices of the rows containing NaN values for a particular column (in this case, A):

```
df[df.A.isna()].index
```

Then pass the result to the `drop()` function:

```
df.drop(df[df.A.isna()].index)
```

Comment: `df.test_variable is None`  makes no sense in pandas.